# visual basic ReRoll If Lands on Double

Tags: vb.net, random

I'm having trouble with my code. Here I have to make it, so if both `intNum1` & `intNum2` create a double they must reroll until it isn't a double. This is my current code. The issue is when I do run the program and both intNum1 & intNum2 happen to roll on the same number creating the double it doesn't automatically reroll. Basically both intNum should never equal each other
Im sure it most likely is something very simple but any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
    Dim randGen As New Random
    Dim intNum1 As Integer
    Dim intNum2 As Integer
    Dim intTotal As Integer
    Dim intRoll As Integer


    intNum1 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
    intNum2 = randGen.Next(1, 7)


    Select Case intNum1
        Case 1
            PicDie1.Image = picOneDot.Image
        Case 2
            PicDie1.Image = picTwoDots.Image
        Case 3
            PicDie1.Image = picThreeDots.Image
        Case 4
            PicDie1.Image = picFourDots.Image
        Case 5
            PicDie1.Image = picFiveDots.Image
        Case 6
            PicDie1.Image = picSixDots.Image
    End Select

    Select Case intNum2
        Case 1
            picDie2.Image = picOneDot.Image
        Case 2
            picDie2.Image = picTwoDots.Image
        Case 3
            picDie2.Image = picThreeDots.Image
        Case 4
            picDie2.Image = picFourDots.Image
        Case 5
            picDie2.Image = picFiveDots.Image
        Case 6
            picDie2.Image = picSixDots.Image
    End Select

    Select Case intRoll
        Case 1
            If intNum1 = intNum2 Or
            intNum2 = intNum1 Then
                randGen.Next(1, 7)
            End If
    End Select


    intTotal = intNum1 + intNum2
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You describe what the code is supposed to be doing pretty well (kudos!), but not what the *specific issue* is. Actually you don't even *mention* any issue. Is there a question?

Comment: your code is correct. what is the problem here?

Comment: why are you triggering a random in introll where in your case is only 1?

Comment: I didnt mean to have that there. I've been trying a lot of different ideas i must not have cleared it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code. Cannot include all the below points in the comments, so using this place holder.

1. Random numbers generated will not be different as you are initializing `Dim randGen As New Random` in the method and probably this method being called multiple times. Refer [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx).
2. `intRoll` is never initialized. So it will always be zero. Hence the `Select Case intRoll` will never evaluate to `Case 1`.
3. If condition `If intNum1 = intNum2 Or intNum2 = intNum1 Then` has same conditions evaluated twice. `If intNum1 = intNum2 Then` should meet your purpose.
4. In the If condition you used `randGen.Next(1, 7)` this value is never assigned to any variable either `intNum1` or `intNum2`. Even if it assigned you need to make sure its not the same again as random number can be same again.
5. Suggestion: Remove the Select case and replace it with `If intRoll = 1 And intNum1 = intNum2 Then`.

Answer (score 0):

If num1 and num2 are the same

```
if num1 = num2 then {


intNum2 = randGen.Next(1, 7)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop that runs while intnum1 and intnum2 are equal

'Initialize the variables so that they are equal for first run

```
Dim randGen as New Random
Dim intNum1 as Integer = 0
Dim intNum2 as Integer = 0

While intNum1 = intNum2 'reroll until the are not equal
   intNum1 = randGen.Next(1,7)
   intNum2 = randGen.Next(1,7)
End While

'process your select case to set your images based on their values
```